# Find full name from AD alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have recently migrated from Sybase/SAP ASE to MSSQL Server. master..syslogins in  sybase has two columns name and fullname. Name would be AD alias name and fullname is Full Name of the user. Example...Dan Brown is the user and his AD alias would be BrownD. Now, in SQL Server i created logins using their AD alias. How would i get the full name from the alias name in SQL Server. Is there any function/sp available in SQL Server? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is nothing built in to get anything from AD for the field. Is there a specific need for it? The domain sid should be sufficient for auditing.

Comment: yes, this is part of auditing as they are looking similar to Sybase details....select suid, status, accdate, totcpu, totio, spacelimit, timelimit,
resultlimit, dbname, name, language, pwdate, audflags, fullname,
srvname, logincount from master..syslogins

Comment: I usually end up writing a PowerShell script for such use cases, because as Sean mentioned nothing OOTB in MSSQL gives you this data.

Comment: ok....Thanks to Sean and LowlyDBA....

Comment: You are able to query AD data using [ADSI](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/30/sql-server-query-active-directory-data-using-adsi-ldap-linked-server/), [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/). Create a function which returns that you want using login name as an input parameter.